# Getting NZEC Error while submitting solution in codechef

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

This is my code for a particular question on codechef :

```
n=int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    a,b =input().split()
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    x=[int(q) for q in input().split()]
    x.sort(reverse=True)
    new_x=[item for pos,item in enumerate(x) if x.index(item)==pos]
    last=new_x[b]
    i=x.index(last)
    ans= i - 1 + x.count(last)
    print(ans)
```

It passes all the test cases when I try it on my own environment but shows runtime (NZEC) when I submit the solution.
I searched a lot on internet but not able to figure out the problem.
Please help me out.